# Swift - cancel thread when new string arrives

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

the code below allows me to create a typewrite effect on a UITextView, but I want to know how to cancel the thread running when a new string comes to be printed

So if I have two strings

```
var a = "aaaaaa"
var b = "bbbbbb"
```

and the string a is halfway printed "aaa" it stops and then just go on with "bbbbbb", because at this moment my code gives me something like "aaababababbb"

```
extension UITextView {
    public func typewrite(text: String, timebetweenletters: TimeInterval, fontsize: Float) {
        self.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: CGFloat(fontsize))
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.userInteractive).async {
            Helper.write(text)
            var writing = Helper.read()
            for (_,caracter) in text.characters.enumerated() {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.text = self.text! + String(caracter)
                }
                Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: timebetweenletters)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One approach would be to use an operation queue instead of GCD.  It supports cancellation and your code can test whether a cancel has been issued.

Comment: Take a look at [`NSOperation`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/operation), which supports cancellation. Note that a `cancel()` call will not stop an executing operation. It just updates the states of the operation object so the code can decide how to deal with that

Comment: From iOS 8 dispatched blocks support a sort of cancellation. `DispatchWorkItem.cancel(<#T##DispatchWorkItem#>)`